# Display actual URLs of links in moderator flag queue

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

#### Context:

In the moderator flag queue, posts (questions, answers and comments) are a re-styling of the *rendered* post with links stripped out.

Appearance of example post in queue:

> Check out this link

It is not even rendered as an actual link. But the actual URL is relevant to making the decision on what action to take, for example if the link is to a recognised authoritative site vs some high school blog.

#### Problem:

To *see* the actual URL of links, the mod must open the post in a new window then if the mod has a pointing device, hover over the link to display it, and if not (like me, using an iPhone), either edit the post to reveal the source of the post or open it in yet another window and inspect the address bar.

#### Proposed change:

Display the link using raw in-line markdown. For example:

> Check out [this link](http://example.com)

whether or not the link was entered using an in-line type link, or an indexed type link. This would give a standard rendering of links, but also bind the link to the anchor text so it's easier for the mod to scan the post.

Ideally the raw url would itself be an active link (anchor tag), so it could be followed easily if desired.

#### Benefit:

Speed and ease of handling flags.

Comment: You moderate on your iPhone? Kudos, that's... not exactly the easiest thing in the world. ;)

Comment: @hichris123 I thumb in and post code too :)

Comment: Isn't expanding the post enough? It does show the rendered view. Is the problem specifically in a mobile browser?

Comment: @gilles I use the full site on my iPhone (the mobile site near useless). Yes, expanding the post does show the rendered post (it's still another action, just a different one), but without a pointer the only way to discover the link's url is to open it. I would like to be avoid expanding/opening altogether and simply see the url in the flag list.